# One-to-many relationships SQLAlchemy that depend on each other

Tags: python, database, database-design, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to get the following models working together. Firstly the scenario is as follows:

1. A user can have many email addresses, but each email address can only be associated with one user;
2. Each user can only have one *primary email address* (think of it like their current email address).

An email address is a user's id, so they must always have one, but when they change it, I want to keep track of other ones they've used in the past. So far the setup is to have a helper table `user_emails` that holds a tie between an email and a user, which I hear is not supposed to be setup as a class in using the declarative SQLAlchemy approach (though I don't know why). Also, am I right in thinking that I need to use `use_alter=True` because the `users` table won't know the foreign key `email_id` until it's inserted?

`models.py` looks like this:

```
"""models.py"""
user_emails = Table('user_emails', Base.metadata,
                Column('user_id', Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'),
                       primary_key=True),
                Column('email', String(50), ForeignKey('emails.address'),
                       primary_key=True))

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, Sequence('usr_id_seq', start=100, increment=1), 
                primary_key=True)
    email_id = Column(String(50),
                      ForeignKey('emails.address', use_alter=True, name='fk_email_id'),              
                      unique=True, nullable=False)
    first = Column(String(25), unique=True, nullable=False)
    last = Column(String(25), unique=True, nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, first, last):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last

class Email(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'emails'
    address = Column(String(50), unique=True, primary_key=True)
    user = relationship(User, secondary=user_emails, backref='emails')
    added = Column(DateTime, nullable=False)
    verified = Column(Boolean, nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, address, added, verified=False):
        self.address = address
        self.added = added
        self.verified = verified
```

Everything seems OK until I try and commit to the DB:

```
>>> user = models.User("first", "last")
>>> addy = models.Email("example@example.com", datetime.datetime.utcnow())
>>> addy
<Email 'example@example.com' (verified: False)>
>>> user
>>> <User None (active: True)>
>>>
>>> user.email_id = addy
>>> user
>>> <User <Email 'example@example.com' (verified: False)> (active: True)>
>>> Session.add_all([user, addy])
>>> Session.commit()
>>> ...
>>> sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) can't adapt type 'Email' "INSERT INTO users (id, email_id, first, last, active) VALUES (nextval('usr_id_seq'), %(email_id)s, %(first)s, %(last)s, %(active)s) RETURNING users.id" {'last': 'last', 'email_id': <Email 'example@example.com' (verified: False)>, 'active': True, 'first': 'first'}
```

So, I figure I'm doing something wrong/stupid, but I'm new to SQLAlchemy so I'm not sure what I need to do to setup the models correctly.

Finally, assuming I get the right models setup, is it possible to add a relationship so that by loading an arbitrary email object I'll be able to access the user who owns it, from an attribute in the Email object?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have already got a pretty good solution, and a small fix will make your code work. Find below the quick feedback on your code below:

- **Do you need the `use_alter=True`? No**, you actually do not need that. If the `primary_key` for the `Email` table was computed on the database level (as with `autoincrement`-based primary keys), then you might need it when you have two tables with `foreign_keys` to each other. In your case, you even do not have that because you have a third table, so for any relationship combination the `SA (sqlalchemy)` will figure it out by inserting new Emails, then Users, then relationships.
- **What is wrong with your code?**: Well, you are assigning an instance of `Email` to `User.email_id` which is supposed to get the `email` value only. There are two ways how you can fix it:

  1. Assign the email directly. so change the line `user.email_id = addy` to `user.email_id = addy.address`
  2. Create a `relationship` and then make the assignment (see code below).
     Personally, I prefer the option-2.
- Other things: your current model does not check that the `User.email_id` is actually one of the `User.emails`. This might be by design, but else just add a `ForeignKey` from `[users.id, users.email_id] to [user_emails.user_id, user_emails.email]`

Sample code for version-2:

```
""" models.py """
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    # ...
    email_id = Column(String(50),
                      ForeignKey('emails.address', use_alter=True,
                                 name='fk_email_id'), unique=True,
                      nullable=False)
    default_email = relationship("Email", backref="default_for_user")

""" script """
# ... (all that you have below until next line)
# user.email_id = addy.address
user.default_email = addy
```

Comment: This is a great answer, thanks! Assigning the `Email` to the `email_id` in `User` was a typo on my part - I guess that explains the programming error exception? I'm going to go with version two of your solution. PS - does the `use_alter` need to be in their given, as you rightly say, the key is the address (rather than an auto-increment?).

Comment: As I mentioned, your code does not need the `use_alter=True`.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with Python/SQLAlchemy, but here is one way to represent what you want in the database:

[image]

You'd either use deferred constraints (if your DBMS supports them), of leave USER.PRIMARY_EMAIL NULL-able (as shown in the model above) to break the data modification cycle.

---

Alternatively, you could do something like this:

[image]

E-mails belonging to the same user are ordered (note the alternate key on: {USER_ID, ORDER}), and whichever e-mail is on top of that ordering can be considered "primary". The nice thing about this approach is that it completely avoids the circular reference.

Comment: While I think my problem is solved above, that second approach is interesting - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The examples in http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html are close to what you want. I never use an intermediate join table like your user_emails unless I need a many-to-many relationship. user-to-email should be a one-to-many.

For your need to keep track of old email addresses? Add an "obsolete" Boolean attribute to your Email class and filter on that to show current or old email addresses.

Comment: +1: This actually is a very good point - it should be enough to have simple 1-N relationship without helper table.